# What version of Sitecore starts the support of Windows 10?

Tags: upgrade

We are going to upgrade Sitecore platform to Sitecore 8.0, i have a doubt about Sitecore version compatibility.

What version of Sitecore starts the support of Windows 10?  What version will likely work, but not officially supported?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the Sitecore Compatibility Table here: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/087164

And to answer your query, Sitecore 8.0 + supports windows 10

[image]

Comment: just a quick question, would there be any impact on application if we update sitecore platform on windows10

Comment: No theres no impact on the application. whatever be the "impact" will come from .NET framework issues if any